# add images to gridview when button clicked

Tags: android

I follow an android tutorial (link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to make a image view.

I want to display only 10 images and make a button, on click to this adding 10 more images to the grid.

can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea of doing that.

1. change `Integer[] mThumbIds` to a dynamic Array such as `ArrayList<Integer> mThumbIds` (edit: there is also needed to change all related methods to the `ArrayList` methods)
2. create a function to the `ImageAdapter` in order to add more items to the `ArrayList<Integer> mThumbIds` and handle it easier from your Activity.
3. at adapter initialization keep an instance to the adapter so instead of `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));` use something like:
   `// ImageAdapter myadapter;// a field of the activity
   myadapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
   gridview.setAdapter(myadapter);
   // ...
   myadapter.methodToAddMoreItems(itemCollection); // when you need to add the items.`

Comment: thats good but i got some errors when i change integer to array. 1. mThumbIds[position] (The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>) 2. mThumbIds.length : length cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: nice! the idea is to "translate" the simple-array methods to relevant dynamic array methods. ;) happy coding!

Comment: I forget to mention that you will need to call `notifyDataSetChaged()` in your `methodToAddMoreItems`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. What you need is a Endless Adapter. There is s ample to work with. If you still have difficulty ask a question in stackoverflow with commonsware and android as tags for the question.